# jquery/javascript to read select box css/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have inherited some code that sets the css of a select box depending on the option that has been selected. There are many select boxes on the page and my goal is just to get select boxes that have the "failure" css style.

I think that I have got relatively close but I just can't get it to work for me. Relatively close means that I can get the css class displayed in a JavaScript alert box but when I try to use  that text value in an if statement nothing happens.
That code is below.

Any pointers gratefully received.

```
$("select").each(function () {
   alert(this.options.item(this.options.selectedIndex).className);
   if (this.options.item(this.options.selectedIndex).className == 'frm_ddl_notOk') {
      alert('bunter?');
   }
});
```

EDIT 20 hours later...

I am an idiot.
I mispelled the class that I was looking for. Should be "form_ddl_notOk".
It is distinctly depressing how long it took me to notice. Especially after I used a prompt box so I could cut and paste the class name back into my code (and then didn't do it!).

The imperfect code that I posted with my question worked when I used the correct class name.

Here's some background to my question and responses to others questions and comments:

When I find an element in "failure" I will look for a sibling element called "comments" and make it obligatory that "comments" be filled.
I cannot base the selection on the option text 
I must base this on the class and/or bgcolor.
The style is applied to the select element and the option element.
I was using more general selectors just to try to figure stuff out.

Thanks for your replies. Not sure whether I should mark any of them as the "answer". The universe would probably carry on without much amiss if this Q was deleted.

Comment: You want to check the select element or the selected option for the class? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Is there something you plan to do with the `select` elements once you have identified them? Why can't you just use the class selector in jQuery? `$('select option.frm_ddl_notOk').each(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that I posted with my question worked when I used the correct class name.

className == 'form_ddl_notOk'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting all `<select>` elements, change your selector:

```
$("select.frm_ddl_notOk").each(function () {

});
```

This uses the **class** selector ( `.` ) - http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ . It will only return elements with the specific class. So in your case, it will look for all `<select>` elements, then filter them based on whether they have the class "frm_ddl_notOk" or not.

But more readable is:

```
$("select").filter(".frm_ddl_notOk").each(function () {

});
```

That is all if you are targeting a `<select>` element with the specific class (which is what your question seems to explain). But in your code, you seem to be looking at the `<option>` elements (specifically the selected one) to see if they have the class (using jQuery's hasClass - http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ ). If so, you could try something like this:

```
$("select").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find("option").filter(":selected").hasClass('frm_ddl_notOk')) {
        alert('bunter?');
    }
});
```

This will find the *selected* `<option>` element for **every** `<select>` element and if it has the class you're looking at, it will alert.

That uses the `:selected` selector - http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

So I guess my point is if you want to get the selected option, use:

```
$("select").find("option").filter(":selected")
```

If you want to set the selected option, use:

```
$("select").find("option").eq(YOUR INDEX).prop("selected", true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

And finally, if you don't need to operate on the specific `<select>` elements, just use this:

```
$("select").find("option").filter(":selected").filter(".frm_ddl_notOk").each(function () {
    // The <option>s that have the "frm_ddl_notOk" class
});
```

In this one, it finds all `<select>` elements, looks at their `<option>` children, only looks at the *selected* ones, and only with the class "frm_ddl_notOk".

Comment: Is the classname attached to the select element ?

Comment: @adeneo Yeah I'm confused. I keep going back and forth on what to filter. I'm continually editing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("select").each(function () {
   if ($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).hasClass('frm_ddl_notOk')) {
      // do what must be done.
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").each(function (i, ele) {
     if ( $('option:selected', ele).is('.frm_ddl_notOk') ) {
         alert('bunter?');
     }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two areas of improvement in your code:
1) Selector can be more efficient 
2) Your use of "this" is incorrect.  Use either `$(this)` or better yet `$(element)` using the second argument of the `each()` callback function as `element`

```
/*You get your <select class="frm_ddl_notOk"> element*/
$("select.frm_ddl_notOk").each(function(index, element) {
   /* Get the <option> tag like this $(element).find("option:selected") */
   alert("Your option element is "+ $(element).find("option:selected"));
   alert('bunter?');
});
```

If you feel super lazy:
 Use `$("select.frm_ddl_notOk option:selected")` to get all selected `<option>` tags with the `"frm_ddl_notOk"` class in the parent `<select>` tag.